# UIButton touchUpInside event not firing correctly

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uibutton

I have a tableview that contains a row with a custom cell that contains a `UIButton`. However, the button doesn't always fire the action.  Here's my code:

```
   submitButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [[submitButton layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [submitButton setClipsToBounds: YES];
    submitButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [submitButton setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.contentView addSubview:submitButton];
    [submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [submitButton release];
```

This is called in the custom cell's `-(id)initWithStyle:`

The `buttonAction` method looks like this:

```
 -(void)buttonAction
 {
     NSLog(@"Button Clicked!");
 }
```

It seems that the only way I can get the `buttonAction` to fire is if I press down on the button and release somewhere inside the cell's frame, but not inside the button itself.  Why would that be?

****UPDATE****
Problem still exists, but I found that the more consistent way to get the button to fire is to click and drag to the left or right and then let go, as long as I let go within the bounds of the cell/row.

**UPDATE #2**
It looks like if I use iOS 6.0, it works as intended.  But on 5.0 or 5.1 it does not.

Comment: `alloc-init` on `UIButton` creates a button of type `UIButtonTypeCustom`, of which the default properties and settings make **absolutely no damn sense.** At least try setting an appropriate frame to see if it works.

Comment: I set a frame in a later method using [submitButton setFrame:CGRectMake(centerCalc, 0, 200, 65)];

The button shows up fine, that is not the problem.  Also, if I give the button images using setImage:forState: it properly displays the images depending on whether the I've pressed on the button or now.

Comment: What else is in this cell? Any gesture recognizers? That could screw up a button...

Comment: No other gesture recognizers in this cell.

Comment: figured it out - I have a gesture recognizer on the main tableview for clicks on the background that calls a method to hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[submitButton sizeToFit]`. I'm wondering whether your button has any size (since I don't see you giving it any).

Also: Create your button with `[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom]` instead of alloc-init.

Comment: I set the frame in a later method, using:
[submitButton setFrame:CGRectMake(centerCalc, 0, 200, 65)];

Comment: OK but hiding relevant code from people who you are asking to help you is not very nice.

Comment: sorry - wasn't trying to be mean - it just didn't seem like that other method would be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the same method call to `TouchUpOutside` as well - you should then see it work every time. TouchUpInside is only fired if you lift your finger while still within the bounds of the button.

Comment: Yes, TouchUpOutside works as expected.  But it's not what I'm looking for. I want users to be able to simply click on the button and have it work, not have to drag their finger off the button, or across the button.